# How to resolve Email OTP authentication in WSO2 Identity server 5.3.0?

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed the below link [Configure Email Otp](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+EmailOTP+Authenticator) to configure Email otp for two step authentication in WSO2 Identity server.

After giving username and password in the login page, we are supposed to be redirected to Email OTP page but we are getting redirected to https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_notification.do?status=Error+when+processing+the+authentication+request%21&statusMsg=Please+try+login+again.&SAMLResponse=pZLLbsJADEX3%2FYrR7AN5QZIRGYRaISGVTXksuqncxECkZAaNJ1X7900CETQLNl3a8r332PJs%2Fl2V7AsNFVql3Bu5nKHKdF6oY8p326UT87l8mhFUpX8Wb0hnrQjZ6iXlH2EQRbnvxkmWuBiHUQIhHkKYRp%2BTKSTgcbYiqnGlyIKyKfddL3LcxPH9rReISSCCaBS703fO9j2A3wI0SIrEJTLltVFCAxUkFFRIwmZis1i%2FimZUnI22OtMllxdC0QUattSmAvtY23aK3Dl0owKVLezPn%2BzHciBCYxtoLkudQXnSZGfjewrZX21jwdY0KJ91jmwPZY2Pc6ibvl4%2BR8P%2F57Oo7UktoSgx52N5Bb73GtivkQiOKHfNtgwacXuoDNrF2aGzGXj0gkH7Vvc%2FJH8B.

When we checked the logs, we found the below trace,

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 13:53:37,664] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp.EmailOTPAuthenticator}
>   - Unable to get the access token org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Unable to get the access token at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp.EmailOTPAuthenticator.initiateAuthenticationRequest(EmailOTPAuthenticator.java:158)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:64)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:466)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:233)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:175)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:127)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:142)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1004)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:160)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:108)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37).

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to inability to connect your Email provider(server). You can initially do following in order to diagnose,(assuming you are using Gmail)

1. Verify the "userId", "gmailClientIdValue", "gmailClientSecretValue", etc are valid.

`<Parameter name="GmailEmailEndpoint">https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/[userId]/messages/send</Parameter>
<Parameter name="GmailClientId">gmailClientIdValue</Parameter>
<Parameter name="GmailClientSecret">gmailClientSecretValue</Parameter>`

2. Try to invoke the email send with different tool (postman) with the API. This is to verify that the API endpoints are reachable from your machine. This is to exclude any network level port blocking, etc.

Comment: With the same axis2 configuration, I am able to send mail through ESB/EI. Now I am getting the below error in IS .

org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: Error while getting the SMTP configuration
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp.EmailOTPAuthenticator.initiateAuthenticationRequest(EmailOTPAuthenticator.java:226)